# Adding condition in xslt

Tags: xslt

I need help in modifying my conditions in xslt.

I have 3 param in my xsl

```
<xsl:param name="today" select="'19470815'" /> <!-- this is date in yyyyMMdd format -->    
<xsl:param name="categoryID"/> <!-- This is CATEGORYID in xml file -->
<xsl:param name="subCategoryID"/> <!-- This is SUBCATEGORYID in xml file -->
```

My current xsl looks for only `subcategory` and does not look for `category`.

My requirements are:

- If `categoryID` is passed as value `0` then list all categories result
- If `categoryID` is passed then the result should display only for that category id
- If `subcategoryID` is `0` then display result subcategories under mentioned `categoryID` only
- If particular `subcategoryID` is passed then the result should display values from that particular sub category, which comes under selected subcategory
- If `categoryID` and `subcategoryID` is `0` then display all results

The `today` parameter is passed so that no past date result should display.

Please guide me in fixing this xslt. My xml and xslt are below

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$type = 'open' ">

        <xsl:for-each select="//SUMMARYNODE[SUMMARY/SUBCATEGORYID = $subCategoryID and SUMMARY/FORMATTEDDATE >= $today]  ">
            <xsl:sort select="SUMMARY/FORMATTEDDATE " />
            SOME STUFF
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="count(//SUMMARYNODE[SUMMARY/SUBCATEGORYID = $subCategoryID and SUMMARY/FORMATTEDDATE >= $today] ) >= 1 ">
            SOME MORE STUFF
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="not (count(//SUMMARYNODE[SUMMARY/SUBCATEGORYID = $subCategoryID and SUMMARY/FORMATTEDDATE >= $today] )>=1) ">
            NO RECORDS AVAILABLE
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:when>

</xsl:choose>
```

XML Input

```
<root>

    <SUMMARYNODE>
        <SUMMARY>           
            <CATEGORY CATEGORYID="2">OPERATIONS PROCUREMENT</CATEGORY>
            <SUBCATEGORYID>4</SUBCATEGORYID>            
        </SUMMARY>

    </SUMMARYNODE>


    <SUMMARYNODE>
        <SUMMARY>           
            <CATEGORY CATEGORYID="2">XYZ</CATEGORY>
            <SUBCATEGORYID>6</SUBCATEGORYID>            
        </SUMMARY>

    </SUMMARYNODE>

    <SUMMARYNODE>
        <SUMMARY>           
            <CATEGORY CATEGORYID="5">ABC</CATEGORY>
            <SUBCATEGORYID>8</SUBCATEGORYID>            
        </SUMMARY>

    </SUMMARYNODE>

</root>
```

Comment: Please show also wanted output(s) to make question much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the condition you want is as follows

```
<xsl:for-each select="//SUMMARYNODE
    [SUMMARY/CATEGORY/@CATEGORYID = $categoryID or $categoryID = '0']
    [SUMMARY/SUBCATEGORYID = $subCategoryID or $subCategoryID = '0']
    [SUMMARY/FORMATTEDDATE >= $today]">
```

Actually, it is usually better to use an **xsl:apply-templates** rather than **xsl:for-each**. It is still possible to **xsl:sort in this instance.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:param name="today" select="'19470815'"/>
   <xsl:param name="categoryID" select="0"/>
   <xsl:param name="subCategoryID" select="0"/>

   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SUMMARYNODE
         [SUMMARY/CATEGORY/@CATEGORYID = $categoryID or $categoryID = '0']
         [SUMMARY/SUBCATEGORYID = $subCategoryID or $subCategoryID = '0']
         [SUMMARY/FORMATTEDDATE >= $today]">
         <xsl:sort select="SUMMARY/FORMATTEDDATE "/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>

      <xsl:variable name="recordCount" select="count(SUMMARYNODE         
         [SUMMARY/CATEGORY/@CATEGORYID = $categoryID or $categoryID = '0']
         [SUMMARY/SUBCATEGORYID = $subCategoryID or $subCategoryID = '0']
         [SUMMARY/FORMATTEDDATE >= $today])"/>
      <xsl:if test="$recordCount > 1"> SOME MORE STUFF </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$recordCount = 0"> NO RECORDS AVAILABLE </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="SUMMARYNODE">
    SOME STUFF 
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the variable to avoid doing the same calculation twice.